# StreamWriter in Powershell Outputs Blank File

Tags: powershell, file-io, powershell-2.0, streamwriter

Here is the code:

```
$outputPath = "c:\Output"
$scopePath = "$($outputpath)\scopes.csv"
$clientsPath = "$($outputpath)\clients.csv"
$scopeStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($scopePath)
$clientStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($clientsPath)
$scopeStream.WriteLine("Scope,ScopeName")
$clientStream.WriteLine("IP,MAC,Lease,Reservation,Hostname")
$scopeStream.Flush()
$clientStream.Flush()
...
$scopeStream.WriteLine("$($scope.Name),$($scope.Address)")
...
$clientStream.WriteLine("$($client.IP),$($client.MAC),$($client.Lease),$($client.Reservation)$($client.Hostname)")
...
$scopeStream.close()
$scopeStream.dispose()
$clientStream.close()
$clientStream.dispose()
```

The files are created if they don't exist, but nothing is ever written to them.  Perfectly blank files, and I can't figure out why, for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before - usually it's because the StreamWriter is throwing an Exception. You'd think that this would cause an exception in your script, but I've seen cases where it's throwing non-terminating exceptions, so your script doesn't ever receive it.

After running the block of code, try getting the last exception details:

```
$Error[0].Exception | Format-List * -Force
```

If there's an exception, it should help you figure out exactly what is causing the problem. My guess would be that it's a permissions issue.

Comment: I can't check this until Monday, but it certainly can't hurt.

Comment: It turns out that prior runs of the script had terminated before the handles could be closed and disposed, and thus the files were locked.  So I wrapped the New-Object in a try/catch.  The catch closes and disposes, and then does a second (nested) try/catch to  new-object.  If that fails, I just throw an error.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you were able to get it working.